# How to provide a definition for symbols in a LaTeX math equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations

Say I have an equation:

```
x = R + E
```

What's the best way to provide a definition for R and E? Is there a way to include a line under the equation saying what the variables mean (i.e. a "where" clause)? Example:

```
x = R + E
where R is Racoon, E is Elephant
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since mathematics (in general) should form part of the textual flow, one can follow an equation with symbol explanations. This would even include proper punctuation in the equation itself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac velit dolor. 
Nulla nunc dolor, commodo sed consectetur ac, dapibus malesuada odio. 
Mauris porta libero eget nisi placerat quis bibendum tellus fermentum. It is therefore
possible to define the relationship
\[
  x = R + E,
\]
where~$R$ is a racoon and~$E$ is an elephant. Sed suscipit tristique laoreet. 
Nulla mi orci, rutrum sed dapibus sed, elementum nec lacus. 
Phasellus id tellus mi, at rutrum justo. Nullam eget turpis justo, ullamcorper 
pretium mauris.
\end{document}
```

This, in my opinion, is the best way to declare variables or symbols used in an equation. However, if need be, it is possible "to include a line under the equation saying what the variables mean." I'm not sure whether this is the "best way" though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac velit dolor. 
Nulla nunc dolor, commodo sed consectetur ac, dapibus malesuada odio. 
Mauris porta libero eget nisi placerat quis bibendum tellus fermentum. It is therefore
possible to define the relationship
\begin{gather*}
  x = R + E, \\
  \text{where~$R$ is Racoon,~$E$ is Elephant}
\end{gather*}
Sed suscipit tristique laoreet. 
Nulla mi orci, rutrum sed dapibus sed, elementum nec lacus. 
Phasellus id tellus mi, at rutrum justo. Nullam eget turpis justo, ullamcorper 
pretium mauris.  It is therefore
possible to define the relationship
\begin{align*}
  x &= R + E, \\
  \text{where}~R &= \text{Racoon,} \\
  E &= \text{Elephant}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides the mathematical alignment environments (`align*` and `gather`).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Kudos to you for providing multiple examples.

Comment: How would I adapt this to make this equation numbered, unlike what `align*` does? If I do `\text{where}~R &= \text{Racoon,} \\` in an `align` environment, the description would be added as a new equation which is not what I want.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati: You can use `align` and add `\nonumber` to each equation you *don't* want numbered.

Comment: Although this is the traditional approach, I do strongly object. I find it problematic to have the definitions follow the equation in an undefined manner. Sometimes they're missing, sometimes there is a sentence about something different inserted before. And in both cases you do not know whether you will find them if you read on, but are in a state of uncertainty. A constant way of putting the definitions in a place where you can see them at first glance (or see that they're missing), will make reading mathematical texts much easier.

Comment: @ziggystar: Okay...? Nothing in the question nor my answer puts any length of content between the definition and their symbol explanation.

Answer (score 16):

Although I think Werner's answer is the best guideline in general terms, sometimes I need to define variables of an equation in cases that are *not* publishing papers (i.e. making a presentation with slides or writing a course handbook). In those cases I tend to use the `description` environment, customizing its label so that it acts as inline math.

In the `article` class you could redefine the `description` label using:

```
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}
```

and then use the `description` environment to define the variables, such as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}
\begin{document}
It is very unusual to characterize some unknown variable $x$ in terms of animal species,
such as the following:
\[x = R + E\]
where:
\begin{description}
\item[R] is Racoon
\item[E] is Elephant
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

which yields the following output:

[image: Description environment for variables of an equation]

I don't know if its the 'correct' way, but it's very easy to implement, suits my needs and doesn't use the usual `itemize` environment, which I prefer to leave out for regular text.

Answer (score 4):

I´m new to latex but I think you can do it using itemize:

```
\[x = R + E\]
where:
\begin{itemize}
\item[R=] is Racoon
\item[E=] is Elephant
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

I don´t know if itemize is supposed to be used like this, but it works very well for this purpose, particularly if you have a long list of variables.