# Equation and then right-justified comment on same line

Tags: math-mode, formatting

How can I create an equation which is centered, and then comment on it on the same line in a right-justified way? I'm looking for something sort of like this

[image]

But that I basically rigged by putting a bunch of `\qquad`s in there to place it just right. And even there the equation isn't quite centered.

I imagine if the comment was too long I would put it in a `parbox`. But in the one above, I couldn't get the comment to go any farther to the right than that without it skipping a line.

Comment: Related: [How to provide a definition for symbols in a LaTeX math equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36500/5764)

Answer (score 6):

You could load the `amsmath` package, set up an unnumbered display math environment, and use the `\tag*` macro to right-justify the explanatory string. For instance:

[image]

(The vertical lines just indicate the boundaries of the textblock.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag*{Pythagoras}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* -- The method shown above manages to center the equation on the textblock if the argument of `\tag*` is no wider than roughly 1". If you need to typeset more text than fits in a single 1"-long line, I suggest you put it in a `tabular` environment, as follows -- again, the vertical framelines are just there to to indicate the edges of the textblock:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,   % for '\tag*' macro
            array,     % for '\newcolumntype' macro
            ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedLeft' macro
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft}p{#1}}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\[
a^2+b^2=c^2 
\]
\[
a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag*{Pythagoras}
\]
\[
a^2+b^2=c^2 
  \tag*{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}P{1in}@{}}
     Way past the seven hills, in the hut of 
     the seven dwarfs, there lived\dots
  \end{tabular}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A drawback is the equation is not centred w.r.t. the remaining blank space.

Comment: @Bernard - I understood the OP's requirement as wanting to center the equation on the textblock. (For sure, the equation in the OP's screenshot doesn't look like it's centered in the "remaining blank space.) However, I may have misunderstood the objective.

Comment: @Mico I wanted to center it on the textblock.

Comment: @Mico: Maybe you're right. I just wondered. Anyway the typographical effect depends very much on the length of the comment, of the formula, on the equations around. I don't think there is a general rule.

Comment: This appears not to center it on the textblock. If I make the tag longer, it moves the equation left.

Comment: @EricAuld - The equation stays centered as long as the argument of `\tag*` is no wider than 1". Please be specific about the length of the text descriptors you plan to employ.

Comment: You could also try `\tag*{\hskip -100pt Pythagoras' Theorem}` (say).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti - Great suggestion! :-) I've asked the OP to provide specific information about the likely lengths of the descriptors. Let's see what he has to say.

Comment: @Mico I think they could be long...sometimes I think I'd like to make the description a `\parbox` of width 2.5cm or so, and take up a few lines.

Comment: @EricAuld - The method I explain in the addendum to my answer should fit your objective.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{array,tabularx,mathtools}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\[
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}CCR@{}}
    &   $\mod(R,M)\cong  M$  & Any $M$ module $M$
\end{tabularx}

\]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little convoluted, but this also works:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}

Text before.
\begin{flalign*}
    &&a^2+b^2&=c^2
    &\llap{Pythagoras' Theorem}
\end{flalign*}
Text in between.
\[
    a^2+b^2=c^2
\]
Text after.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the code]