# System of equations in single line with indices at end

Tags: equations, labels

I want to write a system of $n$ equation of similar form in a single equation with indices at the end of the equation, for example the following one:

[image]
 I did this by the following commands

```
\begin{equation*} \tag{$\nu=1,2,\ldots,n$}
x_{\nu}^{(0)}=x_{\nu}^{(1)}
\end{equation*}
```

This is a system of n equations with the indexing symbol k takes values from 1, 2, up to n and it has been put in the command of \tag in \begin{equation} - \end{equation}.

Is this the correct way to do this? Or there is an alternative?

---

One problem with this use is the following. Suppose after above system of $n$ equations the statement (sentence) is complete (full-stop). Then putting full-stop after n in the \tag{$\nu=1,2,\ldots,n.$} results completion of the sentence before bracket ), so how to deal with above system of equations?

Comment: See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336464/equation-and-then-right-justified-comment-on-same-line).

Comment: This is much helpful. Thanks for the suggestion.