# Equation with indices at end and to right side

Tags: equations, numbering

I had asked a similar question of the above type (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455803/system-of-equations-in-single-line-with-indices-at-end)), but the output was different (maybe due to the `amsart` package). I did the following:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb, array}
 \begin{document}

  Consider following system of equations: 

  \begin{equation*} \tag{i=1,2,\ldots, m}
  a_i x_i^2 + b_i = 0
  \end{equation*}
  \end{document}
```

In the output, it shows the equation `$a_i x_i^2+b_i=0$` in the middle, and the indices `$i=1, 2,\ldots, m$` appear **at the beginning of the equation**; how can I bring them to the end of the equation?

Comment: My usual suggestion is `a_ix_i^2+b_i=0\qquad(i=1,2,\dots,m)`. The conditions are *inherent to the equations*, not something auxiliary like an equation number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default positions of equation numbers and other tags at document class `amsart` are on the left side of pages. To move them on the right side, you need to add option `reqno` to document class options. This will move  equation numbers  and other tags to the right:

```
 \documentclass[11pt, reqno]{amsart}
 \usepackage{amsmath,,amssymb, array}
 \begin{document}

  Consider following system of equations:

  \begin{equation*}
  a_i x_i^2 + b_i = 0    \tag{$i=1,2,\ldots, m$}
  \end{equation*}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
In the case, when you like to have just this tag on the right side and equation numbers on the left, than the answer of Andrew Swann on [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207458/how-can-i-change-the-position-of-equation-number-locally-if-i-am-not-using-the-a) is handy. Its adaption to your case is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnos}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnos}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\leqnos
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Consider following system of equations:
\begingroup\reqnos
    \[
a_i x_i^2 + b_i = 0    \tag{$i=1,2,\ldots, m$}
    \]
\endgroup
and
    \begin{equation}
    c^2 = y^2 + b^2
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Another options in this case is use the answer of Werner of on [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193535/switch-between-leqno-and-reqno-options-of-amsmath-in-the-same-document), which adaption to your case is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\reqnomode
    \begin{gather*} % <--- works only with amsmath environments
a_i x_i^2 + b_i = 0    \tag{$i=1,2,\ldots, m$}
    \end{gather*}
\leqnomode
and
    \begin{equation}
    c^2 = y^2 + b^2
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be as simple to  use an `flalign*` environment?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array}

\begin{document}

Consider following system of equations:

\begin{flalign*}
    & & a_i x_i^2 + b_i & = 0 &( i=1,2,\ldots, m)
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]