# Roman enumerate inside an align* environment

Tags: align, enumerate, roman

I'm new to latex and i'm writing my first document. I want to specify the conditions for a theorem to be true and i want to format it like this:
 Centered tuple at the top. List of items with roman numeration, each of them aligned on \leq simbol (but roman enumerate still at left)

I wrote this for a previous part

```
\begin{align*}
&AP=(Q,\Sigma,\Gamma,\delta,Q_0,Z_0,F) \\
Q&: Conjunto\ de\ estados \\
\Sigma&: Alfabeto\ de\ entrada \\
\Gamma&: Alfabeto\ de\ Pila \\
\delta&: Q\times(\Sigma\cup\{\lambda\})\times\Gamma \rightarrow  P(Q\times\Gamma^*)\\
Q&_0 \in Q \\
Z&_0 \in \Gamma \\
F&: Estados\ Finales,\ F \in Q
\end{align*}
```

which outputs

[image: Centered tuple with aligned descriptions of each element on ":"]

but instead of aligning to center as the above example i want to enumerate in roman numbers in such a way that numbers stay at left but the content of each conditions stays aligned by comparison symbol (be that <= or =)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to provide a definition for symbols in a LaTeX math equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36500/5764)

Comment: Which `\leq` symbol? There's none in your code.

Comment: Your first order of business should, no doubt, be to encase the strings of text (e.g., "Conjunto de estados") in `\text{...}` wrappers. And, for more-appropriate spacing, instead of `:`, consider writing `\colon`.

Comment: @Mico: I don't think `\colon would be appropriate` here, semantically, as it corresponds to an explanation.

Comment: @Bernard - I will readily admit that my Spanish isn't very good, but isn't "explanation" precisely what's going on here: "F: Estados Finales" (which I assume means "final states")? At any rate, I omitted all ":" symbols in the answer I posted a couple of minutes ago...

Comment: @Mico: What I mean is `\colon` will have too tight a spacing, whereas a real `:` in math mode will be better. That said, we should wait to know what are those mysterious `\leq`…

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest two ways of solving your problem, none of which uses `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tabto} % for the first solution

\newcommand{\defitem}[1]{% for the second solution
  \item \makebox[2em][r]{#1: }\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Defina formalmente $AP$, configuración istantanea
en un~$AP$, cambio de configuración en un~$AP$.

Definición de $AP$
\[
AP=(Q,\Sigma,\Gamma,\delta,Q_0,Z_0,F)
\]
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),leftmargin=4em,align=left]
\item $Q$\tabto{2em} Conjunto de estados
\item $\Sigma$\tabto{2em} Alfabeto de entrada
\item $\Gamma$\tabto{2em} Alfabeto de Pila
\item $\delta$\tabto{2em} $Q\times(\Sigma\cup\{\lambda\})\times\Gamma \rightarrow  P(Q\times\Gamma^*)$
\item $Q_0$\tabto{2em} $Q_0 \in Q$
\item $Z_0$\tabto{2em} $Z_0 \in \Gamma$
\item $F$\tabto{2em} Estados Finales, $F \in Q$
\end{enumerate}

\item Defina formalmente $AP$, configuración istantanea
en un~$AP$, cambio de configuración en un~$AP$.

Definición de $AP$
\[
AP=(Q,\Sigma,\Gamma,\delta,Q_0,Z_0,F)
\]
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),leftmargin=4em,align=left]
\defitem{$Q$} Conjunto de estados
\defitem{$\Sigma$} Alfabeto de entrada
\defitem{$\Gamma$} Alfabeto de Pila
\defitem{$\delta$} $Q\times(\Sigma\cup\{\lambda\})\times\Gamma \rightarrow  P(Q\times\Gamma^*)$
\defitem{$Q_0$} $Q_0 \in Q$
\defitem{$Z_0$} $Z_0 \in \Gamma$
\defitem{$F$} Estados Finales, $F \in Q$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your formatting objective may be achieved by ditching the `align*` environment and, instead, using a good old `tabular` environment. Observe that I don't use any `:` symbols since they're not really needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tabular}{r >{$}l<{$} l }
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{$AP =(Q,\Sigma,\Gamma,\delta,Q_0,Z_0,F)$}\\[1ex]
i)   & Q     & Conjunto de estados \\
ii)  &\Sigma & Alfabeto de entrada \\
iii) &\Gamma & Alfabeto de Pila \\
iv)  &\delta & $Q\times(\Sigma\cup\{\lambda\})\times\Gamma \to  P(Q\times\Gamma^*)$\\
v)   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$Q_0\in Q$} \\
vi)  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$Z_0\in\Gamma$} \\
vii) &F      & Estados Finales, $F\in Q$
\end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: To the downvoter: Please enlighten me as to what's objectionable about this answer.